# How to append and sort the ouput of a command to a file?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to extract http usernames and passwords from a pcap file using tshark and then saving them in a text file. Later, if I want to add some more tuples to that text file, it should not only add new tuples but also remove duplicates in-place, if any.
Command I wrote was-

```
tshark -nr new.pcap.pcapng -T fields -e http.authbasic -Y "http.proxy_authorization" | sort | uniq >> pass.txt | sort | uniq
```

But it just appends the sorted distinct output of the pcap file in the pass.txt file, and then doesnt sort the file again as required. What changes should I make in the above code to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append the data to the file and the command, *then* sort and unique the file in a separate operation:

```
tshark -nr new.pcap.pcapng -T fields -e http.authbasic -Y "http.proxy_authorization" >> pass.txt
sort -o pass.txt -u pass.txt
```

`sort` can do the job of `uniq` (using the `-u` option). By specifying the output file (`-o`) with [the same name as the input file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29698/70524), `sort` will replace the file's contents with the sorted, unique output.

Comment: didn't know about the `sort -u`.... +1

Comment: @Wilf [Not many seem to know about it either](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/76049/70524).

Comment: muru, how about `cat pass.txt <(the_command | sort -u) | sort -u -o pass.txt` ?

Comment: @heemayl I considered that, and decided sorting twice would be more of an overhead than sorting larger data once.

Comment: seconded.... :)